# Removing grid from showing up in shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-grid

I am pretty new to QGIS. I have the following result generated (map shown). The issue I am having is I am not sure how to get rid of gridlines inside the map in a manner that it just shows the outside boundary of the country?

[image]

Comment: Do you use "Graduated color" style?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make the outline of the grid transparent:

   - Open "Layer Styling" panel (F7) for the grid layer.
   - Open "Symbol Settings by clicking symbol button shown in the image below.
   - Select "Simple Fill" style layer.
   - Select "Transparent Stroke" for "Stroke color".
2. If the outline of the country is gone, use "Dissolve tool" under "Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T) > Vector Geometry" for the grid layer. It generates a boundary (in a new layer) from grid layer.

[image]